# Efficient Way of Removing Farthest Point

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a set of points in 3D space with the below example:

```
X       Y      t
1170    303    290
1168    310    291
1171    280    291
1173    310    292
```

When there are multiple instances of t, I would like to calculate the euclidean distance between those instances with t-1 and t+1 and remove the farthest point. The dataset has 100k+ points, but there are rarely more than 3 rows with the same value for t.

Comment: "and remove the farthest point" - which one? One of the points at (t-1) or (t+1), or one of the points at t? If the latter, farthest from what?

Comment: Calculate the center and calculate what point is the furthest from it and remove that point? What have you tried?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille One of the points at t. The point farthest from both (t-1) and (t+1). In this example the point (1171, 280) would be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

```
pts = np.array([[1170, 303, 290],
               [1168, 310, 291],
               [1171, 280, 291],
               [1173, 310, 292]])

pts = pts[np.argsort(pts[:, -1], axis = 0)]    # to sort about last column if not sorted
same_pts = [np.argwhere(i[0] == pts[:, -1]) for i in np.array(np.unique(pts[:, -1], return_counts=True)).T if i[1]>=2]
remove_row = []
for i in same_pts:
    dist = []
    pre = min(i)-1
    post = max(i)+1
    for j in i:
        dist_pre = np.sqrt((pts[pre, 0]-pts[j, 0])**2 + (pts[pre, 1]-pts[j, 1])**2)
        dist_post = np.sqrt((pts[post, 0]-pts[j, 0])**2 + (pts[post, 1]-pts[j, 1])**2)
        dist.append(dist_pre + dist_post)
    remove_row.append(i[np.argmax(dist)][0])
np.delete(pts, remove_row, axis = 0)

'''
Output:
array([[1170,  303,  290],
       [1168,  310,  291],
       [1173,  310,  292]])
'''
```